# Fluid layout, window's width is not resizing on mobile (WP) browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, windows-phone-8, fluid-layout

I am trying to build a simple web layout that would be support for mobile view.
All I've done is  [here](http://okierie.bl.ee/halaman.php). The layout successfully changed on firefox or chrome if I resize the window.
But, when I'm trying to open it on my Windows Phone browser the width of the page is not following my phone's screen width, so the layout is not changed.
I set the layout to be changed (to mobile view) if the window's width is less than 450px.
My phone's width is 400px if it's portrait and 800px if it's landscape.
And here is the source:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
<style>
    body{
        font-size: 15px;
        }
    #navigation{
        height: 50px;
        position:relative;
        max-width : 1100px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        background: #686868;
    }
    #konten{
        position:relative;
        max-width : 1100px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        background: #ccc;       
    }

    #navigation .ifhide{
        display: block;
        float: left;        
    }
    .ifhide{

        width:100%;
        height: 160px;
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 749px){
    .isi{
        width: 68%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        background: #5f0;
    }
    .sidebar{
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        background: #afa;   
        }   
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 748px){
    .isi{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        background: #5f0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .sidebar{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        background: #afa;   
        }   
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 451px){
    #navigation a{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }   
    .home{
        width: 10%;
        height:40px;
        background: #0a0;
    }
    .pictures{
        width: 15%;
        height:40px;
        background: #fa0;
    }
    .videos{
        width: 15%;
        height:40px;
        background: #aff;
    }
    .snd{
        width: 50%;
        height:40px;
        background: #faf;
    }
    .about{
        width: 10%;
        height:40px;
        background: #ffa;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
    #navigation a{
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }   
    .home{
        width: 50%;
        height:40px;
        background: #fa0;
    }
    .pictures{
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        background: #0af;
    }
    .videos{
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        background: #aff;
    }
    .snd{
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        background: #faf;
    }
    .about{
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        background: #ffa;
    }   
    .menu{
        width: 50%;
        height:40px;
        background: #faf;
        float: right;
        }
}
</style>
<script>
    function menu(){
        var itsvar = $(".menu").attr("itsvar");
        if (itsvar == 0){
            $(".ifhide").show({
                easing : "slide",
                duration: 300
                });
            $(".menu").attr("itsvar","1");
        }
        if (itsvar == 1){
            $(".ifhide").hide({
                easing : "slide",
                duration: 300
            });
            $(".menu").attr("itsvar","0");
        }

    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var scrwidth = $(window).width();
        if (scrwidth <= 450){
            $(".pictures").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".videos").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".snd").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".about").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".menu").show();          
            $(".ifhide").hide();
            }
        })
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var scrwidth = $(window).width();
        var isiwidth = $(".isi").width();
        $(".isi").html("width = "+$(window).width()+"<br>height = "+$(window).height()+"<br>width class isi = "+isiwidth);
        if (scrwidth <= 450){
            $(".pictures").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".videos").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".snd").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".about").detach().appendTo(".ifhide");
            $(".menu").show();

        }
        if (scrwidth > 450){
            $(".about").detach().prependTo("#navigation");
            $(".snd").detach().prependTo("#navigation");
            $(".videos").detach().prependTo("#navigation");
            $(".pictures").detach().prependTo("#navigation");
            $(".home").detach().prependTo("#navigation");
            $(".menu").hide();
            $(".ifhide").hide({});

        }
    });
</script>
<nav id='navigation'>
    <a class='home'>Home</a>
    <a class='pictures'>Pictures</a>
    <a class='videos'>Videos</a>
    <a class='snd'>Search &amp; Development</a>
    <a class='about'>About</a>
    <a class='menu' onclick='menu()' itsvar='0' style='display:none'>Menu</a>
    <div class='ifhide' style='display:none;'>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="konten">
    <div class='isi'>
        class isi di sini
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        class sidebar di sini
    </div>

</div>
```

Well, do I have something missed?
Is the jquery mobile really needed for this? (I didn't add it)
Note: I am not test it yet in another mobile browser(android, ios).

Comment: use jquery 2.0 for windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a meta tag in you head section like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Do You know that we have to avoid comment like "+1" or "thanks" here? but I would like to thanks to you, "Thank you!" :D

Comment: By the way, this doesn't support landscape view very well, so if you want it to change width when you switch to landscape, you need to add some extra information like initial-scale="1".  You can read more on this  here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag